# Which program converts sequential code into loop code?

Tags: c#, javascript

Example for sequential code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Sleep(20);
Console.WriteLine("End");
```

Example for loop code(function is being looped):

```
bool step2 = false;
bool step3 = false;
bool beginn = true;
int i = 0;

void looped() //each second
{
  if (beginn == true)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    beginn = false;
    step2 = true;
  }
  if (step2 == true)
  {
    if (i <= 20)
    {
      i++;
    }
    else
    {
      step2 = false;
      step3 = true;
    }
  }
  if (step3 == true)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("End");
    step3 = false;
  }
}
```

Which program converts sequential code into loop code? I want to use it for unity, so c#/mono or javascript output is desired.

In general, what are the right terms for each kind of coding?

Comment: Tell me Is this an Issue in code.? or something else

Comment: what is it you want to **achieve** by converting sequential code into "loop code"? The closest thing I can think of there is "iterator blocks" and "async blocks" (which have significant compiler re-writing) - but: it is not clear whether either of those apply. What is it you actually want to achieve here?

Comment: 1. What is the problem.  2. How does this compile if `i` has been defined in your `begin` method but not in `looped`, please show the full code.

Comment: Since this is Unity, I think you're looking for their coroutines and `yield WaitForSeconds(1)` paradigm: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Coroutines_26_Yield.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is Unity, I think you're looking for their coroutines and `yield WaitForSeconds()` paradigm: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Coroutines_26_Yield.html

```
void Begin()
{
    StartCoroutine("looped");
}

IEnumerator looped() //each second
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(20);
    Console.WriteLine("End");
}
```

EDIT: JavaScript version:

```
looped();

function looped()
{
    print("Hello");
    yield WaitForSeconds(20);
    print("End");
}
```

EDIT: If this is intended to be called from the `Update` method, you need to use the `StartCoroutine` method to start `looped`.

C#:

```
void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine("looped");
}

IEnumerator looped() //each second
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(20);
    Console.WriteLine("End");
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function Update()
{
    StartCoroutine("looped")
}

function looped()
{
    print("Hello");
    yield WaitForSeconds(20);
    print("End");
}
```

Comment: Is looped(); to be in the update() function? Also: How do I use things like Slerp? See here what I want to do http://pastebin.com/ZGRpDmdF

Comment: If you want it to be fired from the `Update` method, you need to use the `StartCoroutine` call. (I will edit my answer)

Comment: Also: How do I use things like Slerp? See here what I want to do pastebin.com/ZGRpDmdF

Comment: Check up on the documentation, read some manuals, check out some of the demo applications that Unity provides. http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html

Comment: @PeakReconstructionWavelength I suggest you create a new question addressing your new issue _specifically_, or consider asking in the [Unity3D user forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/forum.php) where there will be users who are far more familiar than I (and most StackOverflow users) on how to "use things like Slerp" _effectively_ in Unity.